# How to find closest vectors to a certain point

Tags: python, vector

I have thousands of multidimensional sentence-embedding vectors and want to calculate the closest (euclidean distance) 4 to certain predefined clusteroids. Same would appear multiple times if they are right between two points, some would not appear at all if they are way off.

example, lets say I have 6 vector:

```
[1 0 3 1]
[2 1 2 1]
[3 4 1 1]
[1 0 3 1]
[2 1 2 1]
[3 4 1 1]
```

And now I want to know what are the closest **4** vectors to the points `[1 1 1 1]` and `[2 2 2 2]`.

How would I calculate that and what would be the easiest way in terms of computingpower? - I am happy to use already existing librarys.

Edit: I added another dimension to the points to point out the fact that I am operating in the n-dimensional space

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then update you question with minimal example and desired output.

Comment: First on a topological point of view many distances exist, so you should specify what is your definition of *closest* here - by default I would assume Euclidian distance. Then you should also say if you only want pure Python or is numpy is an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `numpy.linalg.norm` to calculate the (Euclidean) distances, then `numpy.argsort` for sorting the point indices according to their distance.

```
import numpy
points = numpy.array([
    [1, 0, 3],
    [2, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 1],
    [1, 0, 3],
    [2, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 1]
])

distances = numpy.linalg.norm(points - numpy.array([[1, 1, 1]]), axis=1)
print(distances)
print(numpy.argsort(distances))
```

The output is

```
[2.23606798 1.41421356 3.60555128 2.23606798 1.41421356 3.60555128]
[1 4 0 3 2 5]
```

The first line lists the Euclidean distances of each point in the list to the reference point. The second line gives the point indices sorted according to their distance: The closest point is 1, second-closest is point 4, third-closest is point 0, ...

Comment: I dont understand the resulting argsort output [1 4 0 3 2 5]. can you shed some light on it?

Comment: I assume it means the third point is the closest to [1 1 1], but it is not